# How can i place a gap between outlines?

Tags: html, css

Are outlines allowed to overlap the last row seems to over lap i  have no clue how to put a gap. the first row seems to seems to have a proper gap with the second row. but the bottom row outline seems to overlap the containers outline. I have tried adding margins and padding but to no avail.
any links or explanations would help.

```css
.container{
  width:312px;
  outline: red dotted thin;
  margin:auto;
}

.floater1{
  width:100px;
  outline: green dotted thin;
  float:left;
  margin:2px;
  padding-bottom:2px;
}

.floater2{
  width:100px;
  outline: blue dotted thin;
  float:left;
  margin:2px;
  padding-bottom:2px;
}

.abit{
  width:96px;
  outline: yellow dotted thin;
  margin-left:2px;
  margin-right:2px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="floater1">
    <img src="halal.png" width="98" height="100" alt="Holy logo"/>
    <div class = "abit">text goes here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="floater2">
    <img src="halal.png" width="98" height="100" alt="Holy logo"/>
    <div class= "abit">text goes here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="floater1">
    <img src="halal.png" width="98" height="100" alt="Holy logo"/>
    <div class= "abit">text goes here and here here here here here here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="floater2">
    <img src="halal.png" width="98" height="100" alt="Holy logo"/>
    <div class= "abit">text goes here here here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="floater1">
    <img src="halal.png" width="98" height="100" alt="Holy logo"/>
    <div class= "abit">text goes here and here here here here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="floater2">
    <img src="halal.png" width="98" height="100" alt="Holy logo"/>
    <div class= "abit">text goes here and here here here here here here 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm either not seeing it or misunderstanding--can you be more specific about where this overlap is?

Comment: _“Are outlines allowed to overlap”_ – they do not change element measures (and therefor positions) they way a border would. // Not totally sure what you are asking here, but maybe you just want to increase the margin between your elements here by a little, so that they have more space in between them in the first place …?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that the container is not enclosing its contents, you can just add `overflow: hidden` to the container.

```
.container {overflow: hidden;}
```

If that causes any issues, there are other "clearfix" options. As said, though, it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I personally hate to work with floating elements in HTML and CSS. Regarding your question, I would define the `.container` class as `display: flex;` and your floating elements as flexboxes `flex: 1;`. 
For further reading on FlexBoxes and stuff see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp.